# Persist Google Maps API Routes result

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps-api-3

I have a form with "start\end" location search, that show me a route between the places found at google maps api. The user can do adjustments at the sugestted route (Draggable=true). The result in the screen is initial place, end place, total km and full route renderezed with the function:

> directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("trajeto-texto"));

How Can In persist, save or generate the final result to a JSON file or string to show to the user in a next step of my application ?
I´m using C# ASPNET MVC

[User Search Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM3c7.png)

```
<form>
    <div>
        <label>Endereço de partida*:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtEnderecoPartida" name="txtEnderecoPartida" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="chegada">Endereço de chegada*:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtEnderecoChegada"/>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Distancia">Total km:</label>
        <input readonly="readonly" type="text" id="distance" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" id="btnEnviar" name="btnEnviar" value="Buscar" />
    </div>
</form>

<div class="col-md-8">
    <div id="mapa"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><div id="trajeto-texto"></div> <!-- for render fullroute -->
</div>


<script>

        var map;
        var directionsDisplay;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        function initialize() {
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ draggable: true });
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-18.8800397, -47.05878999999999);

            var options = {
                zoom: 5,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), options);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("trajeto-texto"));

            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {

                    pontoPadrao = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                    map.setCenter(pontoPadrao);

                    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                    geocoder.geocode({
                        "location": new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
                    },
                    function (results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            $("#txtEnderecoPartida").val(results[0].formatted_address);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
            else { alert('Não foi possível identificar sua localização atual'); }
        }

        initialize();

        $("form").submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var enderecoPartida = $("#txtEnderecoPartida").val();
            var enderecoChegada = $("#txtEnderecoChegada").val();

            var request = {
                origin: enderecoPartida,
                destination: enderecoChegada,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };

            directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                    google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function () {
                        directions = directionsDisplay.getDirections();
                        // Display the distance:
                        alert(directions.routes[0])
                        document.getElementById('distance').value = directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
                        $("#txtEnderecoPartida").val(directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_address);
                        $("#txtEnderecoChegada").val(directions.routes[0].legs[0].end_address);
                        //document.getElementById('origin_latitude').value = directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_location.lat();
                        //document.getElementById('origin_longitude').value = directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_location.lng();
                        //document.getElementById('destination_latitude').value = directions.routes[0].legs[0].end_location.lat();
                        //document.getElementById('destination_longitude').value = directions.routes[0].legs[0].end_location.lng();
                        //document.getElementById('duration').value = directions.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value + " seconds";
                    })
                }

                else {
                    alert("Falha:" + status)
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it !

1st I serialize the maps result... and save at the database

> var serialize = JSON.stringify(result);

then ....
Load the result with ajax

function Inicializa() {

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            traditional: true,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            url: '/Request/GoogleMapsJSON',
            context: document.body,
            data: { id: id },
            success: function (result) {
                LoadMap(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                //debugger;
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                alert("Erro ao renderizar mapa ...");
            }
        });
    }

    Inicializa();

    var map;
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    function LoadMap(result) {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ draggable: false });
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-18.8800397, -47.05878999999999);

        var options = {
            zoom: 5,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), options);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(JSON.parse(result));
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("trajeto-texto"));


    }
```